# Find and Replace specific number at specific location in array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an array containing numbers.

```
A = [1 0 5 6 2 4 5 7 8 8 3 2 1 0 0 1 0 0];
```

I have calculated peaks and locations of these numbers in an array.

```
pks  = [6  8  1 ]
locs = [4  9  16]
```

Now I want to update the array with the new peaks value that I have calculated and plot it.

**Example.**

- I have received peaks `[6, 8, 1]` at locations `[4, 9, 16]`.
- I have altered the peaks values e.g. (`pks-1`).
- I want to replace the peak values in the original array with the new values `[5, 7, 0]`.

Like this.

```
% replace: ↓         ↓             ↓
A = [1 0 5 5 2 4 5 7 7 8 3 2 1 0 0 0 0 0];
```

Is there any trick to do this in MATLAB?
Thanks a lot.

**Example Code**

```
A = [1 0 5 6 2 4 5 7 8 8 3 2 1 0 0 1 0 0];
[pks,locs] = findpeaks(A);

for i=1:length(pks)     
    if (pks(i)==locs(i))
        pks_1(i)=(pks(i)-1);
        A_copy(A_copy==pks(i))=pks_1(i);
    else 
        goto if 
    end
end
```

Comment: `A(locs)=values?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly index them, replace your example code with the following:

```
A = [1 0 5 6 2 4 5 7 8 8 3 2 1 0 0 1 0 0];
% We aren't interested in the actual pks values, so use ~ instead
[~,locs] = findpeaks(A)
% Reduce all values at 'locs' by 1
A(locs) = A(locs) - 1;
```

---

Note, there were several errors in your code. For instance,

- you are comparing `pks(i) == locs(i)`, have a think about what that's actually comparing because it doesn't find when your loop is at a peak. For that you would need a double loop

  ```
  for jj = 1:numel(pks)
      for ii = 1:numel(A)
          if (ii == locs(ii))
              % Peak is at index ii
          end
      end
  end
  ```

  Better would be

  ```
  for ii = locs
     % Peak is at index ii
  end
  ```

  **Even better would be the direct indexing I've shown at the top of this answer!**
- You are also indexing `A_copy` and `pks_1` before they're defined, so that could cause issues.
- Also I'm not sure what you think the `goto` statement is doing?!

Comment: Thats great thanks a lot its perfect and upvoted + accepted. Thanks for ur time and help.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help